# How to center text in <div> when there is also a button on the right of <div>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The text in the `span` is not exactly in the middle due to the `button` on the right. Any help in centering it would be very much appreciated. I've tried adding divs and changing the display property to no avail.

https://jsfiddle.net/9nvukjxa/17/

HTML (uses Bootstrap):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="myflash  alert alert-dismissable speechwarning">
        <div class="container">
            <span>This is not exactly centered</span>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the `button` element out of the natural flow of the document by declaring its position *absolute*.
With a few other minor adjustments, like declaring `position: relative` on the containing parent element `.container`, you should find the text in question now precisely horizontally centered since the `button` element is no longer occupying space in the document flow.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Additional */

.alert-dismissable .close.pos-absolute {
    position: absolute;
    right: -7px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="myflash  alert alert-dismissable speechwarning">
    <div class="container">
      <span>This is not exactly centered</span>
      <button type="button" class="close pos-absolute" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nvukjxa/18/)

Answer (score 0):

There is additional `padding-right` on `.alert-dismissable`. You can override this with `!important`.

You also need to take `.close` button out of the document flow using `position: absolute`.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.alert-dismissable {
  padding-right: 15px !important;
}


.myflash.alert-dismissable .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="myflash  alert alert-dismissable speechwarning">
    <div class="container">
      <span>This <strong>is</strong> exactly centered</span>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```